# REST. Update resource which ID changes on update

Tags: rest, web-services, service

Which method (`PUT` or `POST`) should I use for resource update operation when resource `ID` changes on every update?

What would be the best practice in this situation?

To my mind I should use `PUT`.
But in this case `PUT` won't work twice (won't produce the same results), because id was changed on server side and after each put I should `GET` these edited resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST for adding a new resource and PUT to update the existing resource by the ID.

Comment: yeah, but what if after update using PUT method the ID is changed to some random value which you dont know? In that case you can't use PUT method twice, because object ID was changed, so PUT is not idempotent here